# Darker areas on paint where I previously applied filler

Tags: painting

Recently I painted walls in bathroom with latex water-dispersion paint. The walls were quite even, except some minor defects and a few major ones. I applied "acrylate" filler (that's what the can says) on those defects. In case of major defects I appiled about 4 millimeters of filler. I let the filler dry out, sanded it and applied two layers of paint.

Now I see that the paint coating is slightly darker where I applied a thick layer of filler. I suppose the filler hasn't dried completely and now releases moisture and this propagates through paint.

Do I take any special measures or just wait till it dries up? How long should I wait? Have I screwed it?

Comment: did you spot prime/seal the filler before you painted? If not, a second coat should solve the problem.

Comment: @shirlock homes: I only primed the walls before applying the filler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wait for a couple of days to see if the filler (which maybe absorbed water from the paint) dries completely and then the color matches.  But since you didn't prime the filler (or maybe it didn't dry completely), possibly where it was thick, it has modified the color of the paint.  If the area is still darker after a couple of days of letting the paint/filler dry, then I would apply primer to those areas and repaint.  Hopefully you can use the same roller nap and get a good match on texture so you will not have to repaint the entire wall.

Comment: Looks like it really influenced the paint color. Three days have passed already and there're absolutely no changes. Priming and repainting those spots is not a problem to me at all, so I'll just do it.

Answer (score 1):

pretty common problem. the filler or Spackle will absorb more moisture than the other painted surfaces and offers a lighter background color. Give the effected areas a quick brush coat of paint, let it dry, then put a second coat on entire wall. Should help alot. Good luck.

Comment: Actually in my case the areas treated with filler are *darker* and supposedly the filler *releases* water, that's why I expect them to dry at some moment and putting more coats will surely slower that process.

Comment: agree if filler is new...