# Painitng over caulk leaves a sheen. How can I remove it?

Tags: painting

I painted walls that were touched up using paintable caulk instead of filler.  When painted it left shiny spots.  What can I do to get rid of the shine?

Comment: If you want it to look uniform, you need to have a uniform surface under the paint and caulk, while it may be paintable, doesn't take paint the way drywall or products  intended to finish drywall does.  If I were doing it I'd dig the caulk out, re-do it with some drywall compound or spackle, and then repaint.

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4578/darker-areas-on-paint-where-i-previously-applied-filler?rq=1

Comment: I would first try to sand with fine sandpaper and see if this roughens the surface to remove or reduce the shine. Alternatively, touch up with primer and then redo with the paint.

Comment: No need to dig the caulk out. I'd just blend in a little touchup. Feather it out and you might be good to go.

Comment: When ever a wall is patched the patched area needs to dry then be spot primed with a coat of what you are going to finish the walls with. Let the spots dry then proceed with painting. Try coating over the spots again and see if the sheen disappears